# Retrieve all matching values from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a json array.  I want to retrieve all "tag" values where `listid=n`;

```
[
    {"listid":"1","tag":"ONE"},
    {"listid":"1","tag":"TWO"},
    {"listid":"1","tag":"THREE"},
    {"listid":"2","tag":"ONE"},
    {"listid":"2","tag":"TWO"},
    {"listid":"2","tag":"THREE"},
    {"listid":"2","tag":"FOUR"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"ONE"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"FOUR"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"TWO"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"SIX"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"FIVE"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"THREE"}
]
```

I have found how to search an array for an individual value, but I can't seem to find anything on returning multiple values I require, as a json array.

Comment: Have you tried filter?  `list.filter(el => el.listid===n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first `filter` for the items you want, then `map` to get the specific property you are after.

```js
let a = [
    {"listid":"1","tag":"ONE"},
    {"listid":"1","tag":"TWO"},
    {"listid":"1","tag":"THREE"},
    {"listid":"2","tag":"ONE"},
    {"listid":"2","tag":"TWO"},
    {"listid":"2","tag":"THREE"},
    {"listid":"2","tag":"FOUR"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"ONE"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"FOUR"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"TWO"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"SIX"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"FIVE"},
    {"listid":"3","tag":"THREE"}
]

let n = "2"
let found = a.filter(item => item.listid === n).map(item => item.tag)

console.log(found)
```

This is assuming you want to do this in javascript